# Uninstalling gems massively

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using ruby 2.2 and I would like to know is there is a way to uninstall all gems in my gemlist in one command. Something like `gem uninstall *` or `gem uninstall -A` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
gem uninstall --all
```

Uninstalls every gem in your gem list.